# Get table view of prometheus metrics (POD) in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I would like to get some sort of table view in prometheus where I would like to see the max memory usage, the requested memory and memory limit of a POD.

I already have the PROMQL to put this in a graph (using sum), but how can I get these metrics combined, and in a table format:

| POD | Consumed memory | Requested memory | Memory limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 328MB | 500MB | 1GB (or 1000MB) |

Expression for memory:

`sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod="XYZ", container!="", image!=""}/1000000) by (pod, node)`

`max(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{pod="XYZ", resource="memory"} / 1000000) by (pod)`

Comment: What is you exact problem? You don't know how to join metrics? Or how to query them? Or how to show them in table?

Answer (score 0):

Make a table panel and then make three different querys each one in a table format, then you need to make a inner join -in the data transformations- using a field. Now you just need to use the organize field data trasnformations

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).